# How to open NetBeans methods tree panel?

Tags: java, methods, netbeans6.5, gui-builder

I just closed the methods tree panel in netbeans but now I cannot find how to open it back. I need to see the code methods and fields in a tree view. Where can I reopen the panel in netbeans?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

press ctrl + 7 if I understand what you mean

Comment: Yeah, it worked :) I forgot it is called as navigator :*) Thank you Felix! But is there a menu option for this ctrl + 7 ?

Comment: Yes, there is. Window -> Navigating -> Navigator.

Comment: For mac please press cmd + 7

Answer (score 2):

You can open the navigator window from the menu "Window / Navigating / Navigator" or just press CTRL + 7.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of Netbeans, click on Navigator. You can also go in the Window menu, Navigator.